# Material Angular force light/dark theme on single component

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material2

i configure two Material themes in my angular application.

```
@include mat.all-component-themes($lightTheme);

.dark {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($darkTheme);
}
```

and all works fine, when i add "dark" class to "html" tag, the theme switch to dark mode.

In the application, my sidebar is always dark so i need to use a "mat-select" with light style even if dark theme is selected.

There is a mode to force a material component to use a specific style?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Can you add the "light" theme to the mat select?

e.g

```js
<mat-select panelClass="light"></mat-select>
```

Comment: I think that it doesn't work in all cases.

For mat-select, the background color is assigned to class ".dark .mat-select-panel" (element with class "mat-select-panel" descendant of element with class "dark" (html node). 

Using panelClass property the class "light" and the class "mat-select-panel" would be on the same element. 

I should specify the "light" class for the parent element (eg mat-select-panel-wrap)